# Python while loops end too quickly, without taking into account the input I give

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The title explains the whole problem. The specific code I am struggling with is this block:

```
 raceloop = True
    while raceloop == True:
        race = input("And what type of creature are you?\n")
        race = race.lower()
        if race == "elf" or "orc" or "human" or "dragonborn" or "halfling" or "tiefling" or "gnome" or "dwarf":
            raceloop = False
        elif race == "help":
            print("Pick a race. The valid races are: Elf, Orc, Human, Dragonborn, Halfling, Tiefling, Gnome and Dwarf.")
            continue
        else:
            print("That is not a valid race. Type \"Help\" for help.")
    classloop = True
    while classloop == True:
        pclass = input("And what profession do you have?\n")
        pclass = pclass.lower()
        if pclass == "barbarian" or "bard" or "cleric" or "druid" or "fighter" or "monk" or "paladin" or "ranger" or "rogue" or "sorcerer" or "warlock" or "wizard":
            classloop = False
        elif pclass == "help":
            print("Pick a class. The valid races are: Barbarian, Bard, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Monk, Paladin, Ranger, Rogue, Sorcerer, Warlock and Wizard.")
            continue
        else:
            print("That is not a valid class. Type \"Help\" for help.")
```

It accepts anything into the race and class fields.

Here is the entire code if it is needed, however I did make a few more files for functions and things.

```
import dice
import functions

playerinfo = functions.load()
playerinfo = playerinfo.split(",")
level = playerinfo[0]
if level == "":
    print("It looks like you are just beginning, or your data has been corrupted.\nYou will now be started from the beginning.")
    name = input("What is your name?\n")
    raceloop = True
    while raceloop == True:
        race = input("And what type of creature are you?\n")
        race = race.lower()
        if race == "elf" or "orc" or "human" or "dragonborn" or "halfling" or "tiefling" or "gnome" or "dwarf":
            raceloop = False
        elif race == "help":
            print("Pick a race. The valid races are: Elf, Orc, Human, Dragonborn, Halfling, Tiefling, Gnome and Dwarf.")
            continue
        else:
            print("That is not a valid race. Type \"Help\" for help.")
    classloop = True
    while classloop == True:
        pclass = input("And what profession do you have?\n")
        pclass = pclass.lower()
        if pclass == "barbarian" or "bard" or "cleric" or "druid" or "fighter" or "monk" or "paladin" or "ranger" or "rogue" or "sorcerer" or "warlock" or "wizard":
            classloop = False
        elif pclass == "help":
            print("Pick a class. The valid races are: Barbarian, Bard, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Monk, Paladin, Ranger, Rogue, Sorcerer, Warlock and Wizard.")
            continue
        else:
            print("That is not a valid class. Type \"Help\" for help.")



else:
    item1 = playerinfo[1]
    item2 = playerinfo[2]
    item3 = playerinfo[3]
    pclass = playerinfo[4]
    race = playerinfo[5]
    name = playerinfo[6]
    stage = playerinfo[7]




functions.save("1","Magic Sword","Potion","Magic Axe",pclass,race,name,"1")
functions.savestats("20","20","20","20","20","20","20")
```

I tested a bunch of words with it, all of the classes and races with varying capitalisation, and every single possible way to write the word help. These shouldn't matter because I make the string lowercase first, but I thought i'd try anyway.

Comment: You should check what your chain of `or`s actually evaluates to.

Comment: if race == "elf" or "orc" ... should be if race == "elf" or race  == "orc"...